# Fastest way to input all the numbers on one line in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My problem is "time limit exceeded" error for a problem on SPOJ. As I thought this error is because of large input, I need your help to find the best way to handle large inputs.

Let me explain the input and my code.

> Input
>
> The first line of the input contains test cases t(1<=t<=100). It is
>   followed by 2*t lines, 2 for each test case. The first line of input
>   for each test case contains a number n (0<=n<=10^6), followed by n
>   elements in the next line. Each number is from -10^3 to +10^3

Here is an example of input

```
3 #number of test cases (t)

4 #number of elements that will come to next line (n) (this can be 10^6)

2 1 2 2 #this line may have 10^6 numbers

6 

1 1 1 2 2 2

5

1 2 4 5 1
```

Problem is asking if a number occurs more than n//2 times.
Example output

```
YES 2  #because 2 appears 3 times.

NO     # no number occurs more than n//2 times

NO     # no number occurs more than n//2 times.
```

More information about the problem

> Added by: Troika::Bytes Date: 2010-02-18 Time limit:  1s Source
>   limit:    50000B Memory limit:    256MB Cluster:  Pyramid (Intel Pentium III
>   733 MHz) Languages:   All except: PERL 6

http://www.spoj.com/problems/MAJOR/

And finally my code.

```
from collections import Counter
import re

def major(n):
    s = input().split() # get all the numbers one by one
    y = (Counter(s)).most_common()[0]  # Count how many times a number occurs in the input and return the most occurence with its value in a pair.
    if y[1]> n//2: #if the most occurence is more than half of the "n"
        return "YES " + y[0] # return the value belongs to the most occurence
    else:
        return "NO"

for i in range(int(input())): #get the number of test cases
    print(major(int(input()))) # calling the function to get the "n"
```

I've changed the input part to `s = re.findall(r'\d+', input())` after wondering if `s = input().split()` could be too slow for like *a million numbers.* But again, I am receiving a "time limit exceeded" error. Could it be related to `Counter` function?

Comment: Although I/O can always be a bottleneck, I think you are focusing on the wrong issue here; what if the first 500k numbers on a line with 1 million digits are all the same? You are then processing another 500k digits for nothing; you'd already have the answer.

Comment: The other problem is that Python 3.2 may just be too slow for the strict limits set. I see only *one* Python 2.7 submission accepted, and 0 Python 3.2 solutions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thought it was the best to use `Counter` instead of calculating the occurences on your own, but now I will think of something different. It shouldn't be about input as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could optimize it in these ways:

- Disable the garbage collection:

  ```
  import gc
  gc.disable()
  ```
- Avoid `string.split` and using `re.finditer`.
- Avoid the `range` and use a while-loop.
- Use `sys.stdin.readline()` instead of `input` (it's way faster) and `sys.stdout.write` intead of print.
- Stop when the occurrences of a number are greater than `n // 2` (also, compute this one time only). You can use a `collections.defaultdict` and check the occurrences before updating.
- Avoid the functions, just put everything in a single loop.
- Sometimes importing the libraries in the `main` function can save time.

Unfortunately as [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) noted, there are no accepted solution for [Python 3.x](http://www.spoj.com/ranks/MAJOR/lang=PYTH%203.2.3) and only one for [Python 2.x](http://www.spoj.com/ranks/MAJOR/lang=PYTH%202.7), and according to the amount of memory spent for solving it, numerix could have used `psyco` (the library on which PyPy is based, much faster than CPython). Unfortunately, since `psyco` has been discontinued, its support has been dropped on the cluster the problem is executed, so it could be that nobody will manage to send accepted solutions until they re-enable the `psyco` or PyPy support.

### Example

```
import gc
gc.disable()

# import psyco
# psyco.full()

def main():
    from collections import defaultdict
    from sys import stdin, stdout
    import re

    pattern = re.compile(r'\d+')
    times = int(stdin.readline())

    while times:
        times -= 1
        threshold = int(stdin.readline()) // 2
        vals = defaultdict(int)
        for x in pattern.finditer(stdin.readline()):
            n = int(x.group(0))
            rep = vals[n] + 1
            if rep > threshold:
                stdout.write('YES ' + str(n) + '\n')
                break
            else:
                vals[n] = rep
        else:
            stdout.write('NO\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**EDIT**

I sent an email to *numerix* and he confirmed that his solution used `psyco`:

> *Yes, my solution for MAJOR uses psyco. I didn't try without psyco, but as there is no other AC Python solution I guess it won't be possible or only with heavy i/o optimization.*

Comment: When I saw the memory that has been used by numerix, I wondered if he could have used psyco. Although it's sad to know that SPOJ doesn't support pypy, and I can't get an accepted answer, it's been great for me to learn new tricks, thanks to you.

Comment: Unless I can find an online judge that supports PyPy, I think I will have to learn C, C++ or C#. I really loved Python, but on websites like SPOJ, it's a pain. Thanks for your information about numerix's solution. I was gonna hit him on SPOJ Forums by sending a private message, but after seeing his last activity on forums, I decided not to.